# How to reproject xarray dataset memory efficiently with chunks and dask?

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray, chunks, zarr

**Context:** I have a netcdf file that I want to reproject. It is a costly operation, and I am learning how to use `dask` and `zarr` to do it efficiently without crashing my RAM.

**Code presentation:** `ds` is a 3D `xarray` dataset (dimensions: `time`, `y`, `x`). This array is in projection `EPSG:32607` and I want it in `EPSG:3413`. To do that, I open the dataset by chunking it with `dask`, and resample it reproject it with `rioxarray`. I then save it as a `zarr` (with either `xarray` or `dask`, idk which one is the best).

**Problems:** I want to do two things:

1. Have the reprojection work on the chunks without crashing my memory.
2. Find valid chunk size automatically so I can save the dataset to `.zarr` through `dask` (last line of code).

How can I do that ?

**Dataset description:**
[image: Dataset description]

**Code:**

```
# Fetch the path for essential python scripts, grab only the variable "v"
#ds = xr.open_dataset('Cubes/temp/Cube_32607.nc', chunks=({'time': 100, 'y': 100, 'x': 100})).v

# Example reproducing dataset the size of ds

start_date = np.datetime64('1984-06-01')
end_date = np.datetime64('2020-01-01')
num_dates = 18206
len_x = 333
len_y = 334
# Generate time dimension
date_array = date_range = np.linspace(start_date.astype('datetime64[s]').view('int64'), end_date.astype('datetime64[s]').view('int64'), num_dates).astype('datetime64[s]')
# Generate spatial dimension
xs = np.linspace(486832.5, 566512.5, 333)
ys = np.linspace(6695887.5, 6615967.5, 334)

# Create example data
v = np.random.rand(len(date_array), len(ys), len(xs))
ds = xr.Dataset({'v': (('time', 'y', 'x'), v)},
                 coords={'x': xs, 'y': ys, 'time': date_array}, chunks=({'mid_date': 100, 'y': 100, 'x': 100}))



# Import pyproj to get the CRS
import pyproj

# Attribute a projection to the dataset (currently missing its projection)
ds = ds.rio.write_crs("EPSG:32607", inplace=True)

# Reproject the dataset
ds = ds.rio.reproject("EPSG:3413",resampling=Resampling.bilinear)

# Save it a zarr
ds.to_zarr('Cubes/temp/Reprojected_Cube/Reprojected_Cube.zarr', mode='w', compute=False)

# Trigger the parallel computation to write the data to the Zarr store (Is this line a better way to do it ?)
dask.compute(ds.to_zarr('Cubes/temp/Reprojected_Cube/Reprojected_Cube.zarr', mode='w'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as far as I am aware reprojection itself in rioxarray isn't dask compatible so you might run into issues.

However there are workarounds using rasterios `WarpedVRT`:

```
epsg_to = 4326
with rasterio.open(f) as src:
    print('Source CRS:' +str(src.crs))
    with WarpedVRT(src,resampling=1,src_crs=src.crs,crs=crs.CRS.from_epsg(epsg_to),warp_mem_limit=12000,warp_extras={'NUM_THREADS':2}) as vrt:
        print('Destination CRS:' +str(vrt.crs))
        ds = rioxarray.open_rasterio(vrt).chunk({'x':1500,'y':1500,'band':1}).to_dataset(name='HLS_Red')

ds = ds.persist()
wait(ds)
ds
```

Using this you would have to open and reproject the netCDF variables individually. You can open an individual netCDF variable using this syntax: `'netcdf:/path/to/file.nc:variable'`

Also see the git issues [here](https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/issues/189) and [here](https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/issues/119#issuecomment-674447208) as well as the [github gist](https://gist.github.com/rmg55/875a2b79ee695007a78ae615f1c916b2) where this code comes.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll wait to have it compute before accepting this as the final answer. It's 3h in so far, still going

Comment: Running for now 36h and no sign of finishing.

`f = 'netcdf:Cubes/temp/Cube_32607.nc:v'
epsg_to = 3413
with rasterio.open(f) as src:
    print('Source CRS:' +str(src.crs))
    with WarpedVRT(src,resampling=1,src_crs=src.crs,crs=crs.CRS.from_epsg(epsg_to),warp_mem_limit=12000,warp_extras={'NUM_THREADS':2}) as vrt:
        print('Destination CRS:' +str(vrt.crs))
        ds = rioxarray.open_rasterio(vrt).ch unk({'x':100,'y':100,'band':20}).to_dataset(name='Cubes/temp/Reprojected_Cube/test.nc')

ds = ds.persist()
wait(ds)
ds
`

Comment: Any idea what is going wrong ? The whole thing is 18206x334x333

Comment: So the parameter `warp_mem_limit=12000` is actually pretty low. It's only 12kb so you might want to try to take that out or tweak that. I haven't done this myself yet, only looked into it quite a bit so unfortunately I can't give much better advice than that.

Comment: I will accept your answer since it works, I think for large datasets I will just have to wait for dask to be implemented in the reprojection. There's some activity on xarray's github about that, so fingers crossed !